# Using Canvas.scale(float, float) with negative values produces unexpected behavior when -1 < scaleFactor < 0

Tags: android, android-canvas

Here's the code i use to test in a `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`

```
final Bitmap img        = ((BitmapDrawable) getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)).getBitmap();
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {             
        View view       = new View(getActivity()) {

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.scale(1f, -1f);
                canvas.translate(0, -canvas.getClipBounds().height());
                canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        getActivity().setContentView(view);
    }
});
Thread.sleep(2000);

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {             
        View view       = new View(getActivity()) {

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.scale(1f, -0.9f);
                canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        getActivity().setContentView(view);
    }
    });
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

In the first case, the image is corrected mirrored along x axis, but in the second case, the scale factor is applied without the image being mirrored.

Am i missing something, or is this a bug ?

Comment: Fails on GT-N7000 with 4.0.4, but works on Logicom E400 with 4.2.2

Comment: And stranger : using a small image (f.e. ic_launcher), this doesn't happen.